# bazel cannot test syntax net in my mac

Tags: linux, macos, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I am trying to run [SyntaxNet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet) on my mac and I followed the steps that listed on [this site](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet) but when I reach the last installation step when bazel test SyntaxNet, I got a problem

This is it:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:syntaxnet user$ bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names     syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
..........
Unhandled exception thrown during build; message: topLevelKey: TARGET_PATTERN:syntaxnet/...
alreadyReported: false
path to cycle:
TARGET_PATTERN:syntaxnet/...
RECURSIVE_PKG:rootedPath=[/Users/user/Downloads/models/syntaxnet]/[syntaxnet], excludedPaths=<omitted>)
PACKAGE:syntaxnet
cycle:
PACKAGE:external
WORKSPACE_FILE:[/Users/user/Downloads/models/syntaxnet]/[WORKSPACE]
...
```

... etc

Comment: What did you choose during configuration?

Comment: If you mean the "bazel" version , I choose  bazel-0.2.2b-installer-linux-x86_64.sh

Comment: Use brew. Install python from brew. And use brew install bazel

Comment: If I have already python. Do I have to install it again from brew?

Comment: Probably not. But I have python from brew also and this error doesn't come for me.

Comment: what bazel do you use? 0.2.2 or 0.2.2b?

Comment: brew install bazel install bazel-0.2.3. I am using that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113911/discussion-between-user3633694-and-khrm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I have the wrong version of Bazel installer. Mac user should use these two

[bazel-0.2.2b-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.2b/bazel-0.2.2b-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh)

[bazel-0.2.2b-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh.sha256](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.2.2b/bazel-0.2.2b-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh.sha256)

When I use these, it works fine with me.